# HTML audio plays on page load although autoplay tag is not used

Tags: javascript, html, django, audio

I have an audio file I want to play with a javascript function. However, every time the page loads the audio file plays. I am not using the autoplay tag however.

Html code:

```
<audio id="myaudio" >
    <source src="{% static 'game/tada.mp3' %}" type = "audio/mp3"/>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
 function reveal(){
 var myAudio=document.getElementById("myaudio"); 
 myAudio.play();
 for (var i = 0;i<10;i++){
   for (var j=0; j<12;j++){
     var div = "#"+String(i)+String(j);
     console.log(div)
     $(div).animate({
     top: j*50+"px",
     left: i*50+"px",
   }, 1500 );
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: don't call myAudio.play() if you don't want it to play...

Answer (score 0):

You have `myAudio.play();` this will be basically the same thing as having the `autoplay` attribute. I guess you copy/pasted the JS code :)

Comment: but it is in a function... is the function being called? If so, that is why, but I would think it shouldn't be...

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see the function, mind the indentation ;)

I have no idea at all. What if you remove all the JS code? If it doesn't play it means that somehow the .play() method is called.

Comment: How would I know, I'm not the owner of the question - I'm just pointing that out. Seems the OP hasn't replied anything yet.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I was confused!